# jsp parameter for request.getParameter("mylink").toString()

Tags: jsp

I have a parameter in JSP URL as

```
'http://www.mydoamin.com':8080/?mylink=http://www.myweb.com/#12345'
```

I want to get the value of parameter `mylink` in my jsp  as:

```
<%
   String conferencelink = request.getParameter("mylink").toString();
   out.println(conferencelink);
%>
```

the `#after` value is not getting printed.

Can anyone guide me how I can solve this? Please note the source URL parameter can not be changed from # format.

Comment: You don't need the toString() call.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://www.mydomain.com:8080/?mylink=http://www.myweb.com/#12345
```

This URL is in [invalid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#List_of_allowed_URL_characters) format. Your mistake is that you didn't URL-encode the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) parameter value of `mylink`, in contrary to the HTTP specification. This way, the `#` part is incorrectly been interpreted as an [URL fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) of the main URL on `http://www.mydomain.com:8080`.

This URL is in valid format:

```
http://www.mydomain.com:8080/?mylink=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myweb.com%2F%2312345
```

You can create such an URL as follows in Java:

```
String url = "http://www.mydomain.com:8080/?mylink=" + URLEncoder.encode("http://www.myweb.com/#12345", "UTF-8");
```

Or as follows in JSP:

```
<c:url var="url" value="http://www.mydomain.com:8080/">
    <c:param name="mylink" value="http://www.myweb.com/#12345" />
</c:url>
<a href="${url}">link</a>
```

Either way, the request parameter will now be properly decoded by the servletcontainer:

```
String mylink = request.getParameter("mylink");
```

Please note that the decoding step takes place fully transparently, you don't need to use `URLDecoder` or so. Please also note that the `toString()` call afterwards is removed as it makes no utter sense. It returns `String` already and calling `toString()` without null-checking would only end up in `NullPointerException` when the parameter is not been specified at all.